# linq query help

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a search method below using linq, my search citeria is based on one table so far but I have a particular citeria which requires another table :

Method:

```
public void search(string s)
{
     var db = new CommerceEntities();
     var products = 
         from p in db.Products
         where (p.ModelName != null && p.ModelName.Contains(s))
                || SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) p.ProductID).Contains(s)
                || (p.ModelNumber != null && p.ModelNumber.Contains(s))
                || (p.Description != null && p.Description.Contains(s))
                || SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) p.CategoryID).Contains(s)
                || //stuck - See comment below

/* so far all in 'products' table, but I have one more citeria here that needs 'categories' table.
Ok, the query in SQL statement will be like this:

select ProductID, ModelName, ProductImage, Unitcost, products.Categoryid
from categories 
join products
on (categories.CategoryID = products.categoryID)
where categories.categoryname = 'necklace' (replace necklace with my parameter 's')
order by products.ModelName

I am not sure how to 'integrate' it with my existing linq query. Please kindly advice. Thanks.
*/
         select new
         {
             // Display the items 
             p.ProductID,
             p.ModelName,
             p.ProductImage,
             p.UnitCost,
             p.CategoryID,
         };

     ListView_Products.DataSourceID = null;
     ListView_Products.DataSource = products;
}
```

Comment: I suggest looking into Full Text Search capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var products = from p in db.Products
            join c in categories on c.CategoryID  equals p.categoryID
            where (/* all you conditions in either tables  */)
            select new
            {
               p.ProductID,
               p.ModelName,
               p.ProductImage,
               p.UnitCost,
               p.CategoryID
               /* plus what ever you want from categories */
            };
```